# Delete all but one timestamped files

Tags: bash, shell, grep, find

I have a set of timestamped files that look like this:

```
./mysql_foo_bar_hostname_table1_mysql_dump_20160927112627.dmp
./mysql_foo_bar_hostname_table2_mysql_dump_20160927121555.dmp
./mysql_foo_bar_hostname_table3_mysql_dump_20160927121703.dmp
./mysql_foo_bar_hostname_table4_mysql_dump_20160927112718.dmp
./mysql_foo_baz_hostname_table5_mysql_dump_20160919122659.dmp
./mysql_foo_bar_hostname_table6_mysql_dump_20160927110851.dmp
./mysql_foo_bar_hostname_table7_mysql_dump_20160927133419.dmp
./mysql_foo_bar_hostname_table6_mysql_dump_20160927100456.dmp
./mysql_foo_bar_hostname_table6_mysql_dump_20160927113037.dmp
./mysql_foo_bar_hostname_table6_mysql_dump_20160927102752.dmp
./mysql_foo_bar_hostname_table6_mysql_dump_20160927095924.dmp
./mysql_foo_baz_hostname_table8_mysql_dump_20160919140536.dmp
./mysql_foo_bar_hostname_table9_mysql_dump_20160927100730.dmp
```

I would like to keep the newest of any files that have the same "prefix" (i.e. the bit before "_`<timestamp>`.dmp" (the prefix being everything up to the timestamp).

For instance, in the list above, I would like to keep `mysql_foo_bar_hostname_table6_mysql_dump_20160927113037.dmp`, all the others have unique "prefixes", so I would also like to keep them. I normally work in bash, but if there is a more efficient way to do it, I'd be glad to know it. Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Before the `_.dmp` do not same same prefixes, the table name  is varying across files? You want newest per table type or overall on what logic?

Comment: Your expected file is no way near the newest, the following files are older than the file you have pointed `./mysql_foo_bar_hostname_table7_mysql_dump_20160927133419.dmp
./mysql_foo_bar_hostname_table3_mysql_dump_20160927121703.dmp
./mysql_foo_bar_hostname_table2_mysql_dump_20160927121555.dmp`

Comment: I have edited my original question. @Inian, it's basically newest per table. Ed Morton, my bad formatting chewed up the example I gave.

Answer (score 1):

One should be careful before batch deleting files. So here is a dry run first. Change to the directory containing these files (`cd $DIR`) and run:

```
ls -r mysql*.dmp|awk 'a[substr($0, 1, match($0,"_[^_]*$"))]++'
```

This should generate list of files you wish to delete. *If that is so*,  pipe the output of above command to `xargs rm` to actually delete those files i.e. run:

```
ls -r mysql*.dmp|awk 'a[substr($0, 1, match($0,"_[^_]*$"))]++'|xargs rm
```

### EXPLANATION

For each *prefix*, it keeps the file whose name has the most recent time-stamp, and removes others. Here, *prefix* means the file's path up to last underscore (`substr($0, 1, match($0,"_[^_]*$"))`). The sort order of file names in `ls -r` output places most recent files of each prefix before older ones. `a[<prefix>]++` ensures that the first entry of each prefix is not printed. `xarg` runs `rm` with the filenames piped in as arguments.

Answer (score 0):

```
eval "$( \
  ls \
  | awk -F '_dump_|.dmp' '
     {
     if ( Dates[$1] < $2 ) Dates[$1] = $2
      else Files[$0]++
     }
     END {
       for (File in Files) if ( Files[File] == 1) print "rm " Files[ File]
       }'
  )"
```

- use awk to create a delete cmd with the "not biggest" time valued files (based on name)
- assuming there are no *space* file name (like in your sample)
- if real time of file are the same as name, a `ls -t` could be usefull
- use a not 'oneliner' to be more explicit, oneliner is easy to made with if needed
- i discourage a bit this kind of work because any case going wrong due to bad file name could occur so a `ls -t ./mysql_foo_bar_hostname_*.dmp` is a minimum of *security*